# Find a class field's comes from another calsses

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public int Test;
    public List<MyClassB> StrTest; 
    public MyClassA()
    {
        StrTest = new List<MyClassB>();
        StrTest.Add(new MyClassB());
    }
}
public class MyClassB
{
    public int value;
}
private string ToStr()
{
    // By Reflection 
}
void main()
{
   MyClassA A = new MyClassA();
   string str = ToStr(A.StrTest[0].value);
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

The output is "A.StrTest[0].value".

The main question is how can find a class field's comes from another classes

Comment: Why do you need reflection??

Comment: I think it's have a solution's form my problem. but it's not mandatory

Comment: `A.StrTest[0].value` is just an `int` and has no memory how it was computed. You could use [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) instead, like `ToStr((A a) => a.StrTest[0].value)` and `string ToStr(Expression<Func<A, int>> expr)` - but it will not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public int Test;
    public List<MyClassB> StrTest; 
    public MyClassA()
    {
        StrTest = new List<MyClassB>();
        StrTest.Add(new MyClassB());
    }
}
public class MyClassB
{
    public int value;
}
private string ToStr(Expression<Action> exp)
{
    string expBody = ((LambdaExpression)exp).Body.ToString();
    // some regex
    return expBody;
}
void main()
{
   MyClassA A = new MyClassA();
   Expression<Action> exp = () => A.StrTest[0].value.Equals(0);
   string str = ToStr(exp);
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

by some hint from Klaus Gütter, this works.thanks